# Multi Dimensional array printing

Tags: php

I'm trying very hard to display this multi dimentional array for past 3 to 4 days to no avail.
All I need to do is to display like below:

carName:
carImage:
days: 
 
amount:  // this is where I'm facing the problem to display all the days and amount related to specific car..One car will have few days and amount quoted for each day.

//pls look at my code and help...  Thanks

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db($database);

    $query_showall = "SELECT rental.*,
                             car_name.*,
                             gallery.*,
                             car_make.* 
                        FROM rental,
                             car_name,
                             gallery,
                             car_make 
                       WHERE car_name.carName_id = gallery.carName_id 
                         AND car_name.carMake_id = car_make.carMake_id
                         AND rental.carName_id   = car_name.carName_id 
                    GROUP BY rental.carName_id";

    $result_showall = mysql_query($query_showall) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row_showall = mysql_fetch_array($result_showall)) {
        $carMake_all = $row_showall['carName'];

        $carmake_1[$row_showall['carName_id']][] = $row_showall;          
    }                                                                   

    foreach($carmake_1 as $make_1=>$name_1) {
        foreach($name_1 as $n_1) {
            echo $n_1['carName'].'<br/>'; 
            echo $n_1['gallery'].'<br/>';

            /* I need to loop through the rental table 
               to retrieve num of days and amount for 
               each car here.. */
            echo $n_1['rental_days'].'<br/>';
            echo $n_1['rental_amount'].'<br/>';     
        }                                                 
    }                                                  
?>
```

edit without GROUP BY But how can I stop the carName and imageName not to repeat ?

```
    <?php
 mysql_select_db($database);


 $query_showall="SELECT rental.*,car_name.*,gallery.*,car_make.* FROM rental,car_name,gallery,car_make WHERE car_name.carName_id=gallery.carName_id AND  
     car_name.carMake_id=car_make.carMake_id   AND rental.carName_id=car_name.carName_id ORDER BY rental_days ASC";



$result_showall=mysql_query($query_showall)or die(mysql_error());
  while($row_showall=mysql_fetch_array($result_showall))
  {
      $carMake_all=$row_showall['carName'];
      $carmake_1[$row_showall['carName_id']][]=$row_showall;

  }                                                                 


            foreach($carmake_1 as $make_1=>$name_1)

                   {

            foreach($name_1 as $n_1)

                     {

                          echo $n_1['carName'].'<br/>'; 
                          echo $n_1['gallery'].'<br/>';
                          echo $n_1['rental_days'].'<br/>';
                          echo $n_1['rental_amount'].'<br/>';


                 }

                  }   

?>
```

Comment: Please format your code and try to be more precise about the problem that you are having.

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated...

Comment: and using a `group by` without any aggregate functions generally makes very little sense as well.

Comment: @Marc B ,I'm using Group by to avoid the images and carname from repeating as many times as rental id for each car.But if I remove the group by the rental table displays correctly,I mean the days and amount.Is there any other way?

Comment: @Mooseman ,yeah I knew but my company refuse to use PDO for maintainability reason.

Comment: @clarkson What I do in situations like that is let the PHP side collect all the data and format it, so if the image is in there twice it just overwrites the previous value. This still returns multiple rows, but the data on the PHP side still only contains one instance where it should because of the over-writing.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell I just formatted ,hopefully it's clearer now, if not please comment here and I will provide more.

Comment: @Mark sorry can you explain in more detail please? If I remove the group by, how can I make images not repeat or how to make it overwrite for the same image? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @clarkson I offered an answer with how I would handle the data structure to get what I think you want.

Comment: There's a nice query trick for this, but please specify all the fields in select statement you are **going to use** and nothing more (no `*` pls). Looking at code I see only 4 non-id fields selected form 4 tables at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll take a shot at this. What I would do is rebuild the array before you try to dump it out so that all your data is organized the way you want it to display, that way at each step of the foreach you can only display what you want.

This code would use your SQL statement without the group by, which as you stated is including all the data.

```
// Start with an empty array...
$cars = array();

// Loop over all your results
while($row_showall = mysql_fetch_array($result_showall)) {
    // Set name, if the ID comes up again, it will be reset but won't hurt anything
    $cars[$row_showall['carName_id']]['name']    = $row_showall['carName'];
    // Set gallery, if the ID comes up again, it will be reset but won't hurt anything
    $cars[$row_showall['carName_id']]['gallery'] = $row_showall['gallery'];

    // Now, we add a new property called 'details' and put a new array in...
    $cars[$row_showall['carName_id']]['details'][] = array(
        // Storing a unique day
        'days'   => ['rental_days'],
        // And a unique amount
        'amount' => ['rental_amount']
    );
}

// Loop over each entry in our array...
foreach($cars as $car) {
    // Print out the name, once
    echo $car['name'] . '<br />';
    // Print out the gallery, once
    echo $car['gallery'] . '<br />';

    // Loop over all the details...
    foreach($car['details'] as $detail) {
        // Print out each day
        echo $detail['days']  . '<br />';
        // Print out each amount
        echo $detail['amount']  . '<br />';
    }
}
```